# Returning true if an object is colliding with another object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a function that returns true if the game object is colliding with anything that has the tag "Ground", however, return is underlined with text "Since 'PlayerController.PlayerController(Collision2d)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression". What changes do I need to make?

```
private CanJump(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Groumd") ;
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you would need a return type `bool` for your method and also have a default return of `false` somewhere:

```
private bool CanJump(Collision2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Groumd") ;
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Which you then can shorten to simply do

```
private bool CanJump(Collision2D collision)
{
    return collision.gameObject.tag == "Groumd";
}
```

---

However .. for such a one liner a method is probably a question of taste but why not directly in the method where you call this use

```
collision.gameObject.tag == "Groumd"
```

instead of that

```
CanJump(collision)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a private function that might be defaulting to a void return type? Give it a bool return type or something and then wherever you are calling the function from check if it's result is true to know if there is a collision or not.